# shell script count consecutive spaces

Tags: shell

I've got a string `h="aaaa  bbb"` which contains 2 spaces between aaaa and bbb,and I want to count the number of spaces in it.However,when I try

```
echo $h|grep -o ' '|wc -l
```

it shows 1 instead of the desired two.
Is there any way not to treat consecutive spaces in string as one?

Comment: `spaces_only=${h//[^[:space:]]/}; echo "${#spaces_only}"` counts total number of spaces, not number of *consecutive* spaces. But then, the OP's original code didn't filter for consecutive spaces either.

Comment: BTW, [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) is another relevant link re: the real/underlying problem (`echo $h` discarding spaces and having other undesirable side effects).